# Mocking a Method with Mockito? but it's an instance inside the called method

Tags: java, junit5

So I've been asked at work to add a JUnit test to my code (our app didn't have testing) but I've hit my head against the wall.
Essentially I need to test MyDataSourceImpl.Java

```
  public class MyDataSourceImpl implements MyDataSource {
       @Autowired
       PropertieService propertieService;

       public HttpResponse execute(String url){
              MyHttpClient myClient = new MyHttpClient(url,propertieService.getProperties());
              HttpResponse response = myClient.performCall();
              this.someOtherStuff(response);
              return response;
       }
    }
```

this is how I run my Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyDataSourceImplTest {
      @InjectMocks
      private MyDataSourceImpl myDataSourceImpl;
      @Mock
      private PropertieService propertieService;
      
      @Test
      public void simpleCall(){
           when(propertieService.getProperties()).thenReturn(new HashMap<String,String>());
           HttpResponse response = myDataSourceImpl.execute("https://nothing.com");
           assertEquals(response,"");
      }
}
```

Now, I can mock the propertieService just fine, but how do I mock the myClient.performCall()? because that tries to call a database and it's never going to work in a Test.
I tried treating MyHttpClient like PropertieService and add a @Mock and a when thenReturn, that did nothing. is there any way to do this?

edit: when I write that "I tried treating MyHttpCliente like PropertieService" I mean that
I added a @Mock private MyHttpClient myClient; to my Test, and added a line like when(myClient.performCall()).thenReturn(new HttpResponse()); to my simpleCall(). and that does nothing, it still tries to execute the real performCall() method.

Comment: "I tried treating MyHttpClient like PropertieService and add a @Mock and a when thenReturn, that did nothing." - Explain what you actually did (show code) and explain what "that did nothing means". Mocking the client is what you would have to do.

Comment: I added a @Mock
      private MyHttpClient myClient; to my Test, and added a line like when(myClient.performCall()).thenReturn(new HttpResponse()); to my simpleCall(). and that does nothing, it still tries to execute the real performCall() method.

Comment: Personally I would inject `MyHttpClient` then mocking is trivial. That is easier said than done, but why does the `MyHttpClient` need to take the URL rather than the `performCall` method?

Comment: I don't know why Weston, that class is from a library made by a different team and they won't change it for my sake. essentially the instance has a variable with the url that it got from the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking of constructors may be possible, but it's a sign that your code isn't structured in the best way possible.

Imagine if it was:

```
public class MyDataSourceImpl implements MyDataSource {
   @Autowired
   MyHttpClient myClient;

   public HttpResponse execute(String url) {
       HttpResponse response = myClient.performCall(url);
       this.someOtherStuff(response);
       return response;
   }
}
```

One fewer dependencies, and easy to mock. All from moving the `url` to the `performCall` method.

## When you can't change MyClient

Create a level of indirection:

```
public interface HttpClientCall {
    HttpResponse performCall(String url)
}

public final class MyHttpClientCallAdaptor implements HttpClientCall {

    private final PropertieService propertieService;

    MyHttpClientCallAdaptor(PropertieService propertieService) {
        this.propertieService = propertieService;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse performCall(String url) {
        return new MyClient(url, propertieService)
    }
}
```

Now depend on `HttpClientCall`:

```
public class MyDataSourceImpl implements MyDataSource {
   @Autowired
   HttpClientCall myClient;

   public HttpResponse execute(String url) {
       HttpResponse response = myClient.performCall(url);
       this.someOtherStuff(response);
       return response;
   }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could change that, but the MyHttpClient class comes from a library made by another team and they won't change it for my sake. I'm forced to always instantiate it with a *new* constructor and call the performCall(), which then performs an HTTP request, designed by them. I can easily mock the methods from autowired services, but with this instantiated object I don't know what to do.

Comment: @niconosave the point here is not to change the implementation of `MyHttpClient`, but the place at which it is created. `MyDataSourceImpl` is your class right? So do it like this answer suggests and you can use Spring's mechanics to get a mock of `MyHttpClient`.

Comment: @niconosave added a way of introducing this without changing it.

Comment: @weston I gave it a try and the Test went perfectly, but sadly that won't do, because using the autowired for that class misses the constructor (with the parameters, very important), which has around a hundred lines of code and are needed for it to work, and so the real performCall() breaks. EDIT: I just saw your new response, I'll respond in a second.

Comment: @weston ok I get it, that way I can just mock MyHttpClientCallAdaptor and it's performCall(). I was hoping that JUnit would have some trick to not have to do something like that, but this works, thank you very much :D

Comment: It might too, I would Google "mocking constructors". Just I would avoid that myself as it leads to fragile tests. You should just care about mocking inputs and verifying outputs. Mocking static methods and constructors starts to go outside of that and mirror the code under test too closely.